# Display multiple oxyplot charts c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I have two oxyplot charts (a lineseries and a rectanglebarseries) in my project. However, I can only display one of them at the same time. I know it is because of how I set the DataContext, but I do not know how to change my code so that both of the charts can be displayed at the same time. How can I achieve that?

The xaml-code of my mainpanel:

```
        <oxy:PlotView x:Name="Plot" Model="{Binding PlotModel}" Margin="171,648,407,0" Background="MistyRose"/>
        <oxy:PlotView x:Name ="Histogram" Model="{Binding HistogramModel}" Margin="445,304,78,459" Background="AliceBlue"/>
```

mainpanel.cs

```
...
    trendModel = new TrendModel("VariableName");
    DataContext = trendmodel;
    Histogram histogram = new Histogram(freq_List, axis_List);
    DateContext = histogram;
```

Parts of my cs-classes:

```
namespace ...
{
    public class Histogram : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public Collection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    private PlotModel histogramModel;
    public PlotModel HistogramModel //{ get; set; }
    {
        get { return histogramModel; }
        set { histogramModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("HistogramModel"); }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public Histogram(List<double> frequency, List<double> axis)
    {
        CreateRectangleBar(frequency, axis);
    }
```

The lineseries cs:

```
namespace ...
{
    public class TrendModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private PlotModel plotModel;
        public PlotModel PlotModel
    {
        get { return plotModel; }
        set { plotModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("PlotModel"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    //Constructor
    public TrendModel(string Name)
    {
        PlotModel = new PlotModel() { Title = Name };
        SetUpModel();
    }
```

Comment: i'm a tad confused, from the xaml i see in your  mainPanel, i'd say you already have it set up properly. all you would need to do is pass it a viewmodel that contains the PlotModel and HistoryModel, then set the datacontext to that viewmodel.

Comment: Hi @TimothyGroote! How do I set up a viewmodel? I am new to wpf and c#. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Basically, a viewmodel is just a class, like your `TrendModel`. in WPF, it may or may not notify the framework of changing dependency properties using constructs like `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DataContext` property of each `PlotView`:

```
trendModel = new TrendModel("VariableName");
Plot.DataContext = trendmodel;

Histogram histogram = new Histogram(freq_List, axis_List);
Histogram.DateContext = histogram;
```

Or define the `PlotModel` and `HistogramModel` properties in the same view model class and set the `DataContext` property of the view to an instance of this class.

Comment: Hi mm8, I do not seem to have a DataContext property for my viewmodels. Plot.DataContext and Histogram.DataContext gives the error: myNameSpace.myClass does not contain a definition for DataContext. Should I add something to my classes? Thank you!

Comment: These are the names of the *controls* in your view: x:Name="Plot". You should probably rename these to something different than the names of your types.

Comment: Oh. THANK YOU! It works perfectly now and I have changed the names to something less confusing!

Answer (score 0):

You should put both the models that are passed to the oxyplot renderers in a separate viewmodel, then use *that* as the datacontext for your `mainPanel`.

something like this :

```
//you might want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for viewmodel classes. 
//i did not do so in this example.
public class MainPanelViewmodel 
{
   public TrendModel PlotModel { get; set; }
   public Histogram HistogramModel { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, the rest should go like this :

```
MainPanelViewmodel vm = new MainPanelViewmodel()
{
    PlotModel  = new TrendModel("VariableName"),
    HistogramModel = new Histogram(freq_List, axis_List)
}

DataContext = vm;
```